# 'Cannot resolve symbol' compiling servlet

Tags: java, regex, servlets

I am using Java Servlet. In there, i have to use regular expression to filter out the text. 
However, the java compiler says at the import of import java.util.regex.Pattern; "can not resolve the symbol"

Thus all my consecutive matcher and pattern functions are not working.

Can not we use regex packages in a servlet? i was not able to use contians function of string as it gave me an error too. Is there any alternative for the same ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;


public class HelloWorldExample extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, ServletException
{
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String keyword = request.getParameter("inputValue");
HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
String temp = "http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=2000&indent=on";
PostMethod pst = new PostMethod(temp);

String XMLstr="<GIS>";
Perl5Util perl=new Perl5Util();

 try{
    cl.executeMethod(pst);
    String xmlstr=pst.getResponseBodyAsString();
    SAXBuilder sax=new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc= (Document) sax.build(new StringReader(xmlstr));
    Element rootElem=doc.getRootElement();
    Element res=rootElem.getChild("result");
    List docs=res.getChildren("doc");
    for(int i=0;i<docs.size();i++)
    {
        out.println("docsSize = " + docs.size());
        Element row= (Element)docs.get(i);
        List strs=row.getChildren("str");
        out.println("strs = " + strs.size());
        out.println("Hello");
        Element strRow=(Element)strs.get(0);
        String strContent=strRow.getText().toString();
        Element strRow1=(Element)strs.get(1);
        String Lati=strRow.getText().toString();
        Element strRow2=(Element)strs.get(2);
        String Longi=strRow.getText().toString();
        Element strRow3=(Element)strs.get(3);
        String FileName=strRow.getText().toString();
        if(strContent.contains(keyword))
        {
                //out.println("XMLstr: ");
                XMLstr+="<File><id>"+FileName+"</id><Lat>"+Longi+"</Lat><Long>"+F+"</Long>";
                //out.println("XMLstr: "+XMLstr);
            }   
        //out.println(strRow.getText());
        break;
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println(e);
}   
}
}
```

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern` - "util" without "s".

Comment: Dude, your spelling! 'contains' not 'contians'. If you misspell the key words then everyone's first guess will be that you misspelt in your code also. Still, it sounds like there may be something up with your development environment. More details about your development environment would be helpful. Do you have an example of some code which does work, and something that doesn't, side-by-side?

Comment: Please show the **exact** code that give the compiler error.

Comment: added the code.. sorry for the typos

Comment: "Thus all my consecutive matcher and pattern functions are not working". There are no 'consecutive matcher and pattern functions' in the code you have posted. But no code will 'work' until you have succeeded in compiling it. And please tell me that 'Tomcat 1.7' is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the package should be `java.util.regex.Pattern` and not `java.utils.regex.Pattern`.

EDIT: are you sure you have the appropriate syntax? (`<%@ page import java.util.regex.Pattern %>`). Maybe you are using an older version of Java? The `Pattern` class was made available in Java 1.5.

To see what version you are currently running, open command prompt or terminal and type in `java -version`. This should yield the Java version you have running on your machine.

Comment: I changed it.. even now i am facing the problem

Comment: @user1290495: I have modified my answe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want `java.util.regex.Pattern`? (not `utils`)

Comment: I changed it.. even now i am facing the problem. Cant i use the package in servlet

Comment: Can you give the error you are getting now? There is no reason you can't use the regex stuff in a servlet.

Comment: Unresolved Symbol. Can not resolve symbol "pattern" "matcher" "..util.regex"

Comment: Can you post your exact source code and give the line number that the error occurs at?

Comment: @user1290495 `matcher` should be `Matcher`. You need to stop being so sloppy about how things are spelt. The compiler won't let you get away with it, and neither will most of your correspondents, colleagues, or managers.